# Limits of zero-inflated negative binomial in % of zeroes

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, zero-inflation

What are the limits of a zero-inflated regression? Specifically, if more than 80% of the data is zeroes, is the ZINB still valid? What is a good rule of thumb or educated way to understand the right threshold for the number of zeroes?